# bundle failure under OS X 10.9 (Preview 3)

Tags: macos, rubygems, bundler

I'm trying to run "bundle update" on OS X 10.9 but it's failing with the following error message:

```
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/FrancisO/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for ruby/util.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/FrancisO/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby
/Users/FrancisO/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:381:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /Users/FrancisO/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:506:in `try_cpp'
    from /Users/FrancisO/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:931:in `block in have_header'
    from /Users/FrancisO/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:790:in `block in checking_for'
    from /Users/FrancisO/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
    from /Users/FrancisO/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
    from /Users/FrancisO/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in `block in postpone'
    from /Users/FrancisO/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
    from /Users/FrancisO/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:280:in `postpone'
    from /Users/FrancisO/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:789:in `checking_for'
    from /Users/FrancisO/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:930:in `have_header'
    from extconf.rb:14:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/FrancisO/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/bcrypt-ruby-3.1.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/FrancisO/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/bcrypt-ruby-3.1.0/ext/mri/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing bcrypt-ruby (3.1.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install bcrypt-ruby -v '3.1.0'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Xcode 5 (Preview 3) has been installed and so are the command line tools. Here is some relevant info:

```
gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.1.61) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0
Thread model: posix

brew update
Already up-to-date.

rvm requirements
Installing requirements for osx, might require sudo password.
Certificates in '/usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem' already are up to date.
Requirements installation successful.
```

I'm not having any issues installing any version of Ruby so far (using rvm). Does anyone have any idea?

Thanks,
Francis

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure your default ruby is 1.9.3-p448. `rvm --default use 1.9.3-p448`

Comment: Wow! I guess p392 was faulty as I couldn't even install it on a clean install of Mavericks. p448 works like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

For me the issue was resolved by installing xcode command line tools. In terminal run:

```
xcode-select --install
```

and then select install in the popup.

I had recently installed xcode 5 and I guess I needed to run the above command after the install and I didn't and somehow that caused `bundle update` to fail.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue , the problem was when upgrading to OSX 10.9 (mavericks) I didn't confirm that I agreed to the license agreement for Xcode . if you type the following

```
gcc --version
```

you should get "You have not agreed to the Xcode license agreements."

once agreed everything worked fine